# Unmarshalling unknown type code exception while reading parcel values in Android 4.4+

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm using `Parcelable` interface and its working fine till `Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean)` but when I install same app on a device running under `Android 4.4+ (Kitkat)` then its crashing while reading from parcel. Its throwing below error :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42acce90: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881383 at offset 1864
```

When try to read :

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("TYPE").contains("SOME_TYPE");
```

I have put `extra` in `intent` like this :

```
 Intent oIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), EventFragment.class);
 oIntent.putExtra("TYPE", "SOME_TYPE");
```

Comment: wait a minute ... are you puting to intent String extra? or instance of some object ? is the `"SOME_TYPE"` string or object SOME_TYPE?

Comment: I'm putting string value as I have described here, "SOME_TYPE" is some string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a long time and much R&D, I came to know that we should not use `ArrayList` inside another `ArrayList`, within a `Parcelable` object. It is causing the issue.

So I end-up with using `Serializable` interface provided by `JAVA`, as both concept are same.

Comment: They both aren't same. Parcelable is a way to go for Android. Parcelable is lot more efficient than Serializable as it has been specifically developed for Android keeping performance in mind. Marshalling and unmarshalling ArrayList inside parcel isn't that hard. If you post your code, I might be able to help you.